# Cython strange behavior on array index

Tags: python, arrays, cython

I'm working on a simple project with Cython that involves an image array and tkinter.
I've simplified the code that works with an image array passed like a double pointer.

```
cdef void cmultiArray(unsigned char** sVideoArray, int currentFrame):
    for x in range (1555200):
        a = sVideoArray[currentFrame][x]
        r = math.floor(x/(960*3)) 
    print ("loop ended")
    return
```

The calling code is:

```
cmultiArray(<unsigned char**> sVideoArray.data, currentFrame)
```

This code crashes on the first loop. But if I replace the line with `math.floor` with these two lines,

```
t0 = x/(960*3)
r = math.floor(t0)
```

or just do not use `math.floor` or comment out the array line, the code works fine.
I get the same behavior if I replace `math.floor` with `int`.

It seems that only the use of functions that take the decimal part creates problems with the index of the array that is used before the operations on the index itself.

Comment: i think you do not need a return statement when you define a void function. Although this could be unrelated to your problem

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice it now, I changed it.  If I define  variables x (index) like int (cdef x int) the code run. But I' ve another problem: if I try to print the variable a, the content of the array at index, the code crash again. 
There must be something I did not understand in the interaction between python variables and c pointers .

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to access invalid memory in `sVideoArray` - this kind of mistake can easily cause crashes to happen on lines unrelated to the actual error. Unfortunately, as shown it's pretty much unsolvable - it really needs a [mcve].